# Controller not updating database in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, view, controller

I am very new to rails, so bear with me. I am trying to update a cell in the database in the column "question_one", after selecting a radio button, but what I currently have is not updating my database efficiently. I am confused about what I am doing wrong.

My controller to handle the input

```
def index
  @users = User.all
end 

def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

def new
  @user = User.new
end

def back
  @users = User.order("name").page(params[:page]).per(1)
end

# WHERE I AM UPDATING
def update
  user = User.where(:id => params[:id]).first
if user && user.update_attributes(params[:user])
  flash[:success] = "Team Member successfully Updated!"
else
  flash[:danger] = "Team Member unsuccessfully Updated!"
end
end

def create
@user = User.new(user_params) 
if @user.save
  if @user.role == 0 
     @user.update_attribute :admin, true
  end
  #log_in @user
  flash[:success] = "Team Member successfully Created!"
  redirect_to users_url
else
  render 'new'
end
end

def edit
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end 

def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
    flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
    redirect_to @user
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end

def destroy
  User.find(params[:id]).destroy
  flash[:success] = "User deleted"
  redirect_to users_url
end

private

def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                               :password_confirmation, :role, :username,    :admin, :question_one)
 end

 # Confirms a logged-in user.
  def logged_in_user
    unless logged_in?
    store_location
    flash[:danger] = "Please log in."
    redirect_to login_url
  end
 end

 # Confirms the correct user.
def correct_user
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  redirect_to(root_url) unless @user == current_user
end

# Confirms an admin user.
def admin_user
  redirect_to(current_user) unless current_user.admin?
end
end
```

My back.html.erb

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
<% result = 0%>
<h4> <%= user.name  %> </h4>
<%= form_for(user) do |f| %>
   <%= f.label :Question_one %>
   <%= f.radio_button :question_one, 1 %>
   <%= f.radio_button :question_one, 2 %>
   <%= f.radio_button :question_one, 3 %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
<% end %>
<%= paginate @users %>
```

I have been staring at this for hours now, so I will really appreciate the help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: which version of rails you are using and have you defined your strong params in controller ?

Comment: I am using Rails 4.2.5 with the c9.io and I don't understand what you mean by strong params?

Comment: can you post your entire controller code. Refer for String params http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html

Comment: @dkp I have updated my code to display my entire controller.

Comment: @user3376654 Why do you have two `update` methods ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Form:

```
<%= form_for(user) do |f| %>
 <%= f.label :Question_one %>
 <%= f.radio_button :question_one, 1 %>
 <%= f.radio_button :question_one, 2 %>
 <%= f.radio_button :question_one, 3 %>
 <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Update action:

```
#WHERE I AM UPDATING
def update
  user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
  if user && user.update_attributes(user_params)
   flash[:success] = "Team Member successfully Updated!"
  else
   flash[:danger] = "Team Member unsuccessfully Updated!"
  end
end
```

Comment: Still no luck :( I am just not quite understanding where the disconnect is. It is recognizing the "team member unsuccessfully updated" so it is going through the if-statement.

Comment: Can you just add this to your form:  `<%= f.hidden_field :id, user.id %>`

Comment: Still acknowledging the unsuccessful flash, but not updating. I have tried moving the hidden_field around, but still nothing.. Any more ideas? I appreciate you helping me

Comment: where you have `user.update_attributes(user_params)` , change it to `user.update_attributes!(user_params)` . This would throw you the error why your record is not getting updated.

Comment: It is still is refusing to update. I just don't know what else to do, the code makes sense to me.

Comment: Did you try the above change in my last comment? Did it throw you any error ?

Comment: In your controller, you have defined two **update** methods . Why you have done that ?

Comment: I have changed the method name to def back, which is also the name of my back.html.erb, so that part is corrected. And yes, i tried the user.update_attributes!(user_params). It did not throw any errors, but it also did not clear anything up.